# Usage of with nested to cat multiple files

Tags: ansible, users

I need to create users inputting from 2 list files as below:

```
cat user.yml
user1
user2
user3

cat group.yml
group1
group2
group3

cat playbook.yml
- name: Add the user
  user:
    name: "{{ item[0] }}"
    group: "{{ item[1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - cat user.yml
    - cat group.yml
```

The two files will get inputs dynamically from other tasks, so I will not be able to mention the list in ['user1', 'user2'] like that. Kindly suggest how to cat two lists using with_nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**Cat two lists using with_nested.**"*

A: For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'user.yml').splitlines() }}"
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'group.yml').splitlines() }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: user1 group1
  msg: user1 group2
  msg: user1 group3
  msg: user2 group1
  msg: user2 group2
  msg: user2 group3
  msg: user3 group1
  msg: user3 group2
  msg: user3 group3
```

The same result gives the *pipe* lookup plugin, .e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat user.yml').splitlines() }}"
        - "{{ lookup('pipe', 'cat group.yml').splitlines() }}"
```

---

[Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) *"... like all templating, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine."*

If the files are stored on the remote host, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat user.yml
user1
user2
user3
shell> ssh admin@test_11 cat group.yml
group1
group2
group3
```

read the files from the remote host first, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - command: cat user.yml
      register: result_user
    - command: cat group.yml
      register: result_group
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ result_user.stdout_lines }}"
        - "{{ result_group.stdout_lines }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  msg: user1 group1
  msg: user1 group2
  msg: user1 group3
  msg: user2 group1
  msg: user2 group2
  msg: user2 group3
  msg: user3 group1
  msg: user3 group2
  msg: user3 group3
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Botka, it is working for me

Comment: You're welcome. I've added an example of the files stored on the remote host.